# CDI Java - Configuração

Tags: java, java-ee, cdi

Criei um projetinho simples contendo uma classe Teste e uma interface TesteInterface.

Na teste interface criei um metodo qualquer só para testar. Na classe Teste eu só coloquei @Inject Service service;

Quando chamo o método da interface, está dando nullpointer.

Oque mais é necessário para usar CDI? Coloquei a dependencia do weld para utilizar as anotações:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-se-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Também criei o beans.xml vazio mesmo, porque li que precisa ter esse arquivo.

Alguém pode me dar uma força com a configuração de CDI?

Answer (score 1):

Era necessário saber em qual servidor você está tentando rodar. 
Se estiver usando um servidor pós java 6 o beans.xml já deveria resolver o serviço, o que imagino não ser o seu caso. Nesse link há um bom conteúdo.
http://blog.caelum.com.br/use-cdi-no-seu-proximo-projeto-java/

Antes de continuar, altere a sua versão do maven para o artifact-id: weld-servlet:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
   <version>2.4.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Assumindo que esteja usando o mais comum para estudos, que é o Tomcat e não estiver em uma versão recente, vou abreviar o conteúdo do link uma vez que os seus jars já foram providos pelo maven:

Crie na pasta META-INF um arquivo chamado context.xml com o conteúdo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Context>
    <Manager pathname=""/> <!-- disables storage of sessions -->
  <Resource name="BeanManager"
      auth="Container"
      type="javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager"
      factory="org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory"/>
</Context>
```

E acrescente a configuração do Weld no web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>   
        org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<resource-env-ref>
   <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
   <resource-env-ref-type>
      javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager
   </resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>
```

Comment: Pedro, estou usando o Tomcat sim, na versão 9. 

Fiz o que você falou mas agora nem consigo iniciar o servidor.

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.spi.BeansXml.getUrl()Ljava/net/URL;
at org.jboss.weld.xml.BeansXmlParser.merge(BeansXmlParser.java:165)


GRAVE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Fiz um projeto de teste para o tomcat 9.
Nele não é necessário as configurações no web.xml, mas seguindo as orientações do Balus C no link a seguir, é melhor manter o context.
http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2013/10/how-to-install-cdi-in-tomcat.html
Vou atualizar a resposta com uma outra versão do weld nas dependências do Maven, provavelmente é isso que está causando seu problema, substitua sua dependência pela nova e faça o teste.

Comment: Pedro, tentei exatamente como tá no link que você mandou, mas não deu certo. Ainda está dando nullpointer da chamada do método da interface que injetei.

Commitei as coisas do CDI no github, você pode me ajudar mano?

https://github.com/guilhermenass/controle-financeiro

Comment: Olhando por cima eu vi que você está injetando o service diretamente e chamando o método, mas como o container saberia qual implementação da interface está sendo utilizada ?
Ao usar o inject você está usando o conceito de inversão de dependência, ou seja, a instanciação do objeto para a ser função do container web e não sua, porém, interfaces só podem ser instanciadas de forma anônima, com uma implementação sendo especificada para o método abstrato. 
Tente injetar diretamente UserServiceBean e me diga o que acontece.

Comment: Eu tentei injetar diretamente o UserServiceBean e continua dando nullpointer.

Comment: Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Olá Guilherme, você conseguiu resolver? Estou com o mesmo problema que você.